# Knockout select binding

Tags: select, data-binding, knockout.js, knockout-2.0

How to prevent select change event fires when the select biding is initiated?  an add button  on the page that will add select dynamically  to the DOM. when each select box is adding to the DOM, the change event is firing rather than I select the item from the select?

Comment: Please, provide a fiddle that reproduces the problem, the last time i had this issue, it was related to binding string values when my options were integers.

Comment: @RicardoMedeirosPenna This thefiddle,http://jsfiddle.net/aroor/DNsgF/ the value i'm binding as string. but still the change event is firing when populating the UI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The thing is that KnockoutJS attempts to find which element of your listbox matches the `requiredItem` observable. There is none in the beginning, which is why it then attempts to set it to the "caption" of the listbox. You did not provide one, so it sets `requiredItem` to the first element of the listbox.

What you could do is add a caption item to your array:

```
self.requireditems = ko.observableArray([
{ desc: "Select an option from the list...", key: 0, editable: false } // ... and then all other items]);
```

and if you really don't want `requiredItem` to be updated:

```
self.selectedItem = ko.observable(self.requiredItems()[0]);
```

Then if you want to know if a valid element has been selected from the list, you could add the following property:

```
self.isValidSelectedItem = ko.computed(function() { 
     return self.selectedItem().id; 
});
```

Comment: if i don't want to bind the selecteditem while populating the list, is there any want to get the selected time after the list is loaded into the DOM?

Comment: I don't think the problem is linked to the moment the list is being loaded. If you have an "options" binding and a "value" binding, the "value" will change inevitably if the selected item is not found in the list... Even binding dynamically after the DOM is being loaded will not change the problem.